# Restoring a single database from mysql enterprise full backup

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysqldump

I am having command to restore all databases from full dump taken by enterprise full backup .Can anyone help me how to restore single database from full dump .

Comment: The table you want to restore is InnoDB or MyISAM? Because there are different approaches depending the engine

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mysql -u root -p --one-database destdbname < alldatabases.sql
```

In the above code substitute destdbname with the database name you want to restore, and alldatabases.sql with the name of your full DB backup.

If you would rather just extract the database dump of the single database from the --all-databases dump file, you can do this with sed using this command:

```
sed -n '/^-- Current Database: `dbname`/,/^-- Current Database: `/p' alldatabases.sql > output.sql
```

Where dbname is replaced with the database name of the database to extract, and alldatabases.sql is the name of your dump file. The result will be saved into the file output.sql.

Comment: MySQL Enterprise Backup does not launch mysqldumps, so you cannot restore it like data in is a mysqldump.